# How do we review and clean up our tags?

Tags: discussion, tags

When asking questions I usually take some reasonable guesses on tagging and then, most of the time, somebody comes along and adds tags that I didn't know existed.  Part of this, at least for me, is that we have a *lot* of tags -- more than twice as many as the most "mature" site I participate on, English Language & Usage.  And the tag view is flat, not hierarchical, so browsing to get a sense of our tag set is nigh unto impossible.

What is the best way to make our tags more tractable?  Should we have a hierarchical list on meta or in the FAQ?  Should we try to review everything and ask "is this tag really necessary?"?

Or do we really have such a diverse range of topics that it's not unexpected that our tag list would run 33 pages?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think a hierarchical list on meta would be a great start. Possibly, some tags will fit multiple places within the hierarchy.

It may be necessary/desirable/possible to cull tags (and, in fact, I've culled a few at various times), but I suspect the vast majority of ours are good to have. (Note that the 33 pages mentioned include synonyms, of which we have many, partially because of variant transliterations.)

---

**Update:** [I've started such a list.](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/996)

Comment: Oh, I didn't realize synonyms also showed up in that list.

Comment: Is there a way to dump the tag info in a format that's easier to edit?  Tag name, synonyms, wiki excerpt into a text file would make it much easier to start a hierarchical listing.  (I figure it's easier, as a first pass, to move things around into groups that way, versus just walking the tag list one tag at a time.)

Comment: @MonicaCellio see http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/q/996