# Systematic list of tags

Tags: discussion, faq, tags

As an answer, or perhaps multiple answers, to this question, should be a hierarchy of the [tags](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/tags) used on [the main site](http://judaism.stackexchange.com).

---

Here's a bare list, excluding synonyms, with * meaning the tag has been incorporated into an answer:

```
* adultery
* agriculture
* aishes-chayil
* am-yisrael-jewish-nation
* animals
* anti-semitism
* arachin-tractate
* ashkenazi
* astronomy
* bal-tashchit-waste
* bal-tosif-no-adding
* balak
* bamidbar-numbers-book-of
* basar-bechalav
* bava-kamma
* bava-metzia
* bechor-firstborn
* bechukosai
* behaalotcha-parsha
* behar
* beit-din-court
* bentching
* beshalach
* bigdei-kehunah
* bikkurim-first-fruits
* birchas-kohanim
* bitul-batel-null
* blessing
* blood
* bo
* book-of-ruth
* borrowing
* bowing-kneeling
* breslov
* brit-milah
* calendar
* candle-lighting
* chabad
* chagim-holidays
* chalav-yisrael-jewishmilk
* challah-shabbat-bread
* chametz-leaven
* chanuka
* chasidut-hasidism
* chassidic-rebbe
* chol-hamoed
* christianity
* chukas
* chulin-tractate
* churban-destruction
* conditional-stipulation
* cooking-bishul
* dairy
* daniel-book-of
* derech-eretz-manners
* devarim-deuteronomy-book
* devorim
* dina-dmalchusa-dina
* edim-witnesses
* eggs
* egypt
* ekev
* eliyahu-hanavi
* elul
* eruv-chatzerot
* estates-inheritance
* evening-night
* ezekiel--the-book
* family-members
* fast-days
* fish
* food
* four-cups-wine
* four-parshiot
* gebrochts
* gentiles
* gerut-conversion
* gezel-stealing
* gid-hanashe
* gid-hanashe
* golus-exile
* grapes-wine
* haftarah
* halacha
* hallel
* hamantashen
* har-sinai
* hashkafah-philosophy
* havdalah
* holocaust-shoah
* honey
* hosea--book-of
* hoshana-rabbah
* idolatry
* inebriation
* isaiah-yeshaya-the-book
* islam
* job-iyov-book-of
* joshua--book-of
* kashering-kosherization
* kashrut-kosher
* ki-tavo
* ki-teitzei
* kiddush
* kiddush-cup
* kiddush-levanah
* kilayim-forbidden-mixture
* kitniyos-semigrain-legume
* kohelet
* kohen-priest
* korban
* lag-ba-omer
* lamentations-eicha
* lashon-hara-slander
* leket-shichecha-peah
* lending-interest-ribbis
* levites-leviyim
* lo-yilbash
* lulav-etrog-arba-minim
* maakeh
* maariv
* maaser-tithes
* mamzer
* marror-bitter-herbs
* maseches-bechoros
* maseches-beitza
* maseches-eruvin
* maseches-gitin
* maseches-kiddushin
* maseches-kinim
* maseches-menachos
* maseches-sanhedrin
* maseches-shabbos
* maseches-shkalim
* maseches-taanis
* masechet-berachot
* masechet-makkot
* masecheth-avodah-zarah
* masei
* mattos
* matzah
* meat
* megillat-esther
* melacha-creative-work
* melachim-kings-book-of
* menora-chanukia
* messiah
* mezuzah
* middos-character-traits
* miketz
* mikvah-ritual-bath
* mincha-afternoon-prayer
* minhag
* mir
* mishlei
* mishloach-manot
* mishna
* mishpatim
* mitzvah
* months
* motzei-shabbos
* mourning-aveilus
* muktzeh
* murder
* musaf
* nachum-book-of
* navi-prophets
* nedarim-vows
* negia
* netilat-yadayim-washing
* nevua-prophecy
* nidah
* nine-days
* nissan
* nitzavim
* non-jewish-holidays
* nozir
* nusach-ari
* nusach-ashkenaz
* nusach-edot-hammizrach
* nusach-sefard
* nuschaot
* oil
* orla-revai
* parashas-emor
* parashas-kedoshim
* parashas-shemos
* parashas-shoftim
* parashas-yisro
* parashat-bereishit
* parashat-chaye-sara
* parashat-ki-tisa
* parashat-lech-lecha
* parashat-metzora
* parashat-noach
* parashat-shelach
* parashat-shemini
* parashat-tazria
* parashat-teruma
* parashat-toldot
* parashat-tzav
* parashat-vayeishev
* parsha-torah-portion
* parshat-korach
* parshat-nasso
* parshat-zachor
* passover
* passover-seder-hagada
* pentateuch-chumash
* pidyon-haben
* pikuachnefesh-danger-life
* pinchas
* plagues-makkos
* prayer-book
* pregnancy-birth
* purim
* rabbis
* repentance-teshuvah
* rosh-chodesh-new-month
* rosh-hashanah-new-year
* safrus
* samuel-shmuel-book-of
* sanhedrin-high-court
* sefer-torah
* sefirat-ha-omer
* selichot
* selling-mechirat-chametz
* separating-challah
* sephardi-mizrachi-eastern
* shabbat
* shabbat-songs
* shacharis-morning-prayer
* shatnez
* shaving
* shavuos
* shehecheyanu
* sheker-false
* shema
* shemona-esrei
* shemos-sacred-names
* shemot-exodus
* shiluach-haken
* shir-hashirim
* shiurim-measurements
* shmini-atzeres
* shmita
* shofar
* shoftim--book-of
* simchat-torah
* slaughter-shochet-shecht
* slave-serve-eved-avadim
* sorcery-magic-kishuf
* stringency-chumrah
* sukkah
* sukkot
* summer
* tachanun
* tallit-gadol
* tallit-katan
* talmud-bavli
* talmud-gemara
* talmud-yerushalmi
* tanach
* tattoo
* tattoo
* techeles
* tefilin
* tefilla
* tehilim-psalms
* tetzaveh
* tevilas-keilim-dipping
* theology
* three-weeks
* time
* time-zone
* tisha-bav
* torah-reading
* torah-service
* torah-study
* tractate-sotah
* transactions
* trees
* trei-asar
* tu-bishvat
* tumah-ritual-impurity
* tzedakah-charity
* tzitzis
* va-eira
* vaeschanan
* vayakhel
* vayechi
* vayeitzei
* vayera
* vayigash
* vayishlach
* yashan-chadash
* yemenite-temani
* yeshiva-school
* yetziat-mitzrayim
* yichud-seclusion
* yirmiyahu--book-of
* yizkor
* yom-haatzmaut
* yom-hashoah
* yom-hazikaron
* yom-kippur
* yom-shabbaton
* yom-tov
* yonah-jonah-book-of
* zemanim
* zimun
15th-of-av
7-mitzvos-of-noach
70-nations
acronyms
adon-olam
adult-learning
agada-stories-legends
age
aguna
ahavat-hashem
ahavat-yisrael
alacrity-for-mitzvot
aleph-bet-letters
aliya-laaretz
allegory-mashal
am-haaretz
amalek
amen
apocrypha
appliances
arabic
aramaic
archaeology
architecture-design
arizal
ark-aron-kodesh
army-military-war
artscroll
aseres-hadibros
aseres-yemei-teshuva
asher-yatzer
astrology
authorship
avot-patriarch-fathers
ayin-hara-evil-eye
baal-teshuva
baby-infant
babylonian-exile
bar-bas-bat-mitzvah
bar-kochva
bathroom
beard
bein-adam-lachavero
beis-hamikdash
binding-of-isaac
biography
birchos-hatorah
black-hats
book-banning
books-generally
borer-separating
borrer
bother-tircha
bread
bribery
brisk
bugs
business
calculation
capital-punishment
cemetery
cemetery-grave
chagiga-tractate
chagim-holidaysshiv
chatzitzah
chatzos
chazzan-prayer-leader
cherem
chesed-kindness
children-parenting
chilul-kidush-hashem
chinuch-education
choleh-sick
choshen-mishpat-civil-law
choson-kallah
chovel-umazik
chutz-laaretz
cities
city-of-refuge
cleaning
clothing
code-cipher-cryptogram
color
commentaries
commentary
communities
concubinage
contradiction-stira
creation
criminal-procedure
current-events
curse
daf-yomi
dance
darchei-emori
daytime
death
death-penalty
demography
derabanan
dictionary
dirty
disposal
divorce
drush
eating
eisav
electricity
emes-truth-honesty
employment
emunah
enemies
english
eretz-yisrael
erev-shabbat
eruv-tavshilin
ervah
eschatology
esther
ethiopian-beta-israel
etymology
even-haezer
evil-resha
evolution
explanation-rec
ezra-nechemya
faith-bitachon-emunah
fire-burning
fool
free-will-bechira
friendship
fruits
funeral-burial-levaya
gabbai
games-toys
gan-eden
gehinnom
gemach
gematria-numerology
genealogy
genevas-hadas
geography
geonim
gifts
glass
golden-calf-egel
grammar-dikduk
gravestone-inscription
haazinu
hachana-prep-for-weekday
hachnasat-orchim-guests
hagbah
hagomel
hair
hair-covering
hakaras-hatov
halacha-theory
halachah-theory
haman
hamotzi-beracha
handedness
handicap-disabled-impair
haredim
hashgacha-pratit
hashkafah
hasidic-story
health-safety-shmira
hearing
heaven
hebrew
hechsher-certification
hefsek-interruption
hellenism
heresy
heterodox
hillel
hishtadlut-effort
historical-figures
history
holy-objects
home-house
honors
hotel
hotzaa-carrying-reshuyot
humor
ikarim
illustrations
imahot-matriarch-mothers
inspection
intellectual-property
intent-accident-purposely
internet
invalid-pasul
jewelry
jewish-books
jewish-date-series
kabbalah
kabbalah-maasis
kabbalat-hatorah
kabbalat-shabbat
kaddish
kaparot
karet
kashruth
kavana-concentration
kavod
kedusha-holiness
kedusha-prayer
kerovim-close-relatives
ketubah
kibbud-av-veim-honoring
kiddush-hachodesh
kiddushin-eirusin
king-david
king-solomon
kippa-yarmulka
kiruv-outreach
kissing
kneading-lash
kol-isha
kol-mikadesh
korbanos-ketores-prayers
kotel-western-wall
kusim
language
lashes-malkot
latid-lavo-future
legal-documents
leil-shabbat
leniencies
lifnei-iver
lighting
liquor-beer
lo-bashamayim-hi
lomdus
loshon-hara
loud-quiet
mabul
machlokes
maftir
maharal
mail
makeh-befatish
malach-angel
malachi-book-of
malchut-royalty
mankind
marit-ayin
marriage
martyr
maseches-beitzah
maseches-kelayim
maseches-makos
maseches-moed-katan
masechet-kutim
masechet-yevamot
masechtot-ketanot
mathematics
meal-seudah
mechitza-partition
medicine
meditation
mekach-taut
melacha-erasing
melchizedek
memory
men-male
menorah
meraked
mesirath-nefesh
mesorah-tradition
mezonot-beracha
mi-yodeya-series
middos-chasidus
midrash
migdal-bavel
mincha-meal-offering
minor-katan-child
minyan
miracle
miriam
mishkan-tabernacle
mishnah-berurah
misnaged
mistakes
mizbeach
mon-manna
money
moon
moshe-feinstein
moshe-rabbeinu
motzi-yedei-chovato
music
mussar-ethics
mysticism-kabbalah
myths
nail-cutting
names
natural-phenomenon
niddah
noach-noah-the-man
noachide-laws
non-food
non-kosher-species
number
olam-haba-world-to-come
oneg-shabbat
opening-the-ark
oral-law
oral-torah
organizatons
orthodox
ouhistory
outer-space
parashanut-torah-comment
parashat-reeh
parashat-vayechi
parashat-vayikra
parashat-vezot-habracha
parnassah-livelihood
parshanut-theory
parshanut-torah-comment
parshat-shelach
parties-celebrations
parts-of-the-body
payot-sideburns
peace-shalom
performance-entertainment
petur-exemption
peyot
phone
pictures
pidyon-shvuyim-prisoners
pirke-avot-ethicsof
pirkei-drebbi-eliezer
plant
politics-government
popular-culture
posek-psak-decisor-ruling
possessed
poultry
priorities
product-recommendation
pronunciation
proof-of-torah
prophecies
protective-casing
provenance
psych-mentalhealth
public-policy
publications
purim-torah-in-jest
quotations
rabbeinu-tam
rabbeinu-yonah
rabbi-akiva-ben-yosef
rambam
ramban
ramchal
rashi
rationalism
real-estate
rebuke-tochacha
recording
religious-articles
resurrection-of-the-dead
reward-punishment
riddle
rif-rabbi-isaac-alfasi
rishonim
russian
sadducees
safek
sages-chazal
salt
samson-raphael-hirsch
science
seasons
seder-taharot
seder-zeraim
see-sight-vision-blind
segulah
semicha
sexuality
shabbetai-tzvi
shaul
sheidim-demons
sheva-brachos
shevatim-12-tribes
shidduchim-dating
shimshon-samson
shlichus-agency
shmuel--the-man
shomrim-bailees
shoteh-mental-incompetent
shovavim-tat
showering-bathing
shulchan-aruch
simchah-joy-happiness
sin
site-policy
sitting-shiva
siyum
size
sleep
smell
snow
social-convention
soloveitchik
song-poetry
soul
sources-mekorot
speech-talking
speeches-addresses
spelling-variants
sport-athletics
stackexchange
standing-sitting
star-of-david
statistics
suicide
swear-oath
swimming
symbols-symbology
synagogue
taamei-mitzvot-reasons
tahanun
tannaim
targum-translation
technology
tefilat-haderech
text
tikkun-chatzot
time-limited-commandments
tobacco-cig-smoking
torts-damages
tosfot
tractate-kerisus
tractate-megillah
tractate-nedarim
translation
transliteration
travel
trop-cantillation
trust-neemanut
tu-bshevat
tur
twins
tying-knots-kosheir
tzaar-baalei-chayyim
tzaddikim
tzaraas-negaim
tzibur-community
tznius-modesty
upsherin
vegetables
vehicles-transportation
vidui-confession
viduy-confession
vilna-gaon
vilna-shas
violence
voting
vowels-nekudot
water
weather
wedding
weights-and-measures
women
words
writing-printing
yael
yahrtzeit
yerushalayim-jerusalem
yibum-chalitza-levirate
yiddish
yigdal
yisro--the-man
yom-yerushalayim
yonah-jonah--the-man
yoreh-deah
yosef
yotzrot
yovel
zealotry
zecharia-book-of
zevulun
zionism
```

Comment: Great!  Thanks for getting this started!

Comment: Let's mark them off or remove them from the bare list as we incorporate them into answers, to make it easier to see what's left.  Ok with you?

Comment: @MonicaCellio, sounds like a plan. (Marking them might be better than removing them until all are placed, as perhaps some will need to be in two places in the hierarchy.)

Comment: I've reordered it alphabetically in case that's more useful; feel free to revert.

Comment: @MonicaCellio: When sorting, I didn't add any asterisks. Sorry for dropping them: I didn't realize. Certainly rollback's fine.

Comment: Great, thanks -- wasn't going to try to parse that diff. :-)  I'll roll back the edited list manually, since you also made some other changes to the question that I don't want to lose.  Thanks for all your work on this!

Comment: @MonicaCellio, and to you.

Comment: much more difficult to deal with a non-sorted list. I can probably sort it while retaining asterixes (asteri?) if nobody minds.

Comment: @HodofHod, please feel free.  Sorry the asterisks mess up sorting; I intentionally put them at the beginning to make scanning for unhandled tags easier, without considering the implications for the sorting script. :-)

Comment: @MonicaCellio I can leave asteri on top.

Comment: @MonicaCellio actually sorting left the asteri on top automatically, So that was actually easier. It's done now.

Comment: @HodofHod, pre-existing asteri, anyway -- new ones will go with their tags.  I'm ok with that.

Comment: @MonicaCellio I can resort the list every once in a while, when I remember. Eventually, almost all of them should be asteried, of course.

Comment: @HodofHod, and when they all are, then we can remove the list from the question.

Comment: @msh210 There are a couple of tags that don't seem to be on the list above, even though they're on the site. (masechet-berachot and parashat-chaye-sara, for example, are on the site, and in the answers below, but it was never above.)

Comment: @HodofHod, those two specifically are newer than the above list. Any others?

Comment: @msh210 why is it [tag:chukas] yet [tag:parashat-shelach]

Comment: @msh210 and, while at it, why chukaS and parashaT-shelach?

Comment: @ShmuelBrin, because different people created different tags. Do you see any benefit to uniformity? If so, perhaps suggest it as a meta post. Note that every tag has (well, most have, and all should have) synonyms from reasonable alternative transliterations.

Comment: @ShmuelBrin Already Been Asked http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/q/679/759

Comment: I propose renaming this question: Tag Index, or: Index of Tags.

Comment: How was this list generated?  Does the code still exist?

Comment: @MonicaCellio, I have no idea how it was generated, and I doubt the code exists. I imagine SEDE can be used to generate the list pretty easily, though.

Answer (score 4):

[tanach](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tanach)

- [pentateuch-chumash](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pentateuch-chumash)

  - [none]

    - [parashat-bereishit](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/parashat-bereishit)
    - [parashat-noach](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/parashat-noach)
    - [parashat-lech-lecha](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/parashat-lech-lecha)
    - [vayera](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vayera)
    - [parashat-chaye-sara](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/parashat-chaye-sara)
    - [parashat-toldot](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/parashat-toldot)
    - [vayeitzei](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vayeitzei)
    - [vayishlach](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vayishlach)
    - [parashat-vayeishev](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/parashat-vayeishev)
    - [miketz](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/miketz)
    - [vayigash](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vayigash)
    - [vayechi](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vayechi)
  - [shemot-exodus](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shemot-exodus)

    - [parashas-shemos](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/parashas-shemos)
    - [va-eira](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/va-eira)
    - [bo](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bo)
    - [beshalach](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/beshalach)
    - [parashas-yisro](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/parashas-yisro)
    - [mishpatim](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mishpatim)
    - [parashat-teruma](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/parashat-teruma)
    - [tetzaveh](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tetzaveh)
    - [parashat-ki-tisa](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/parashat-ki-tisa)
    - [vayakhel](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vayakhel)
  - [nonexistent]

    - [parashat-vayikra](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/parashat-vayikra)
    - [parashat-tzav](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/parashat-tzav)
    - [parashat-shemini](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/parashat-shemini)
    - [parashat-tazria](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/parashat-tazria)
    - [parashat-metzora](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/parashat-metzora)
    - [parshat-acharei-mot](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/parshat-acharei-mot)
    - [parashas-kedoshim](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/parashas-kedoshim)
    - [parashas-emor](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/parashas-emor)
    - [behar](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/behar)
    - [bechukosai](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bechukosai)
  - [bamidbar-numbers-book-of](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bamidbar-numbers-book-of)

    - [parshat-bemidbar](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/parshat-bemidbar)
    - [parshat-nasso](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/parshat-nasso)
    - [behaalotcha-parsha](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/behaalotcha-parsha)
    - [parashat-shelach](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/parashat-shelach)
    - [parshat-korach](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/parshat-korach)
    - [chukas](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chukas)
    - [balak](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/balak)
    - [pinchas](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pinchas)
    - [mattos](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mattos)
    - [masei](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/masei)
  - [devarim-deuteronomy-book](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/devarim-deuteronomy-book)

    - [devorim](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/devorim)
    - [vaeschanan](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vaeschanan)
    - [ekev](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ekev)
    - [parashat-reeh](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/parashat-reeh)
    - [parashas-shoftim](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/parashas-shoftim)
    - [ki-teitzei](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ki-teitzei)
    - [ki-tavo](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ki-tavo)
    - [parashat-nitzavim](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/parashat-nitzavim)
    - [vayelech](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vayelech)
    - [haazinu](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/haazinu)
- [navi-prophets](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/navi-prophets)

  - [joshua--book-of](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/joshua--book-of)
  - [shoftim--book-of](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shoftim--book-of)
  - [samuel-shmuel-book-of](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/samuel-shmuel-book-of)
  - [melachim-kings-book-of](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/melachim-kings-book-of)
  - [yirmiyahu--book-of](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/yirmiyahu--book-of)
  - [ezekiel--the-book](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ezekiel--the-book)
  - [isaiah-yeshaya-the-book](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/isaiah-yeshaya-the-book)
  - [trei-asar](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/trei-asar)

    - [hosea--book-of](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hosea--book-of)
    - [yonah-jonah-book-of](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/yonah-jonah-book-of)
    - [nachum-book-of](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nachum-book-of)
- [non-existent] (ksuvim)

  - [book-of-ruth](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/book-of-ruth)
  - [tehilim-psalms](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tehilim-psalms)
  - [job-iyov-book-of](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/job-iyov-book-of)
  - [mishlei](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mishlei)
  - [kohelet](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kohelet)
  - [shir-hashirim](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shir-hashirim)
  - [lamentations-eicha](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lamentations-eicha)
  - [daniel-book-of](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/daniel-book-of)
  - [megillat-esther](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/megillat-esther)

Comment: Perhaps we should do away with the Sefer tags. Are they really necessary?

Comment: IMO we can be rid of them (for _Chumash_, not for _Nach_) if we retag all the questions that have them with the appropriate (and in some cases currently nonexistent) _parasha_ tag instead.

Comment: @msh210 But what if I want to ask a general question on the book of Devarim, for example? Just use "chumash"?

Comment: speaking of which, should there be ksuvim-writings tag?

Comment: @HodofHod, none of the _D'varim_ questions we have *so far* has been about the book in general. It's certainly conceivable (and more so for _D'varim_ than for the first four), but I think the existence of the tag should await its utility. `:-)`

Comment: Should we also include, for example, [creation] under [parshat-bereishit]; [noach-noah-the-man] under [parshat-noach], etc?

Answer (score 3):

[mishna](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mishna), [talmud-gemara](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/talmud-gemara), [talmud-bavli](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/talmud-bavli), [talmud-yerushalmi](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/talmud-yerushalmi)

- [masechet-berachot](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/masechet-berachot)
- [maseches-shabbos](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/maseches-shabbos)
- [maseches-eruvin](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/maseches-eruvin)
- [maseches-shkalim](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/maseches-shkalim)
- [maseches-beitza](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/maseches-beitza)
- [maseches-taanis](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/maseches-taanis)
- [tractate-sotah](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tractate-sotah)
- [maseches-gitin](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/maseches-gitin)
- [maseches-kiddushin](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/maseches-kiddushin)
- [bava-kamma](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bava-kamma)
- [bava-metzia](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bava-metzia)
- [maseches-sanhedrin](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/maseches-sanhedrin)
- [masechet-makkot](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/masechet-makkot)
- [masecheth-avodah-zarah](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/masecheth-avodah-zarah)
- [maseches-menachos](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/maseches-menachos)
- [chulin-tractate](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chulin-tractate)
- [maseches-bechoros](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/maseches-bechoros)
- [arachin-tractate](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arachin-tractate)
- [maseches-kinim](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/maseches-kinim)

Comment: Don't tags with only one post get deleted after a year if no more posts are added?

Comment: @DoubleAA, I think so. Good thing we're adding them here, then, so they don't remain with one post. `:-)`

Comment: I'm not sure this list will inspire anything. We all know that we can ask about gemara and that every masechet gets a tag if it wants. Whether or not it has one already seems irrelevant. Same for the Tanach list. The other ones though can be useful for seeing which tags exist in the field you're asking about.

Answer (score 3):

(Huge undertaking, please help, criticize, etc.)

- [halacha](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/halacha),  see also [minhag](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minhag)

  - Halachic concepts

    - [bitul-batel-null](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bitul-batel-null)
    - [conditional-stipulation](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/conditional-stipulation)
    - [dina-dmalchusa-dina](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dina-dmalchusa-dina)
    - [edim-witnesses](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/edim-witnesses)
    - [stringency-chumrah](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/stringency-chumrah)

---

(Should be ordered according to Mishneh Torah. I'll try to do that)

- [mitzvah](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mitzvah)
    - [bal-tashchit-waste](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bal-tashchit-waste)
    - [bal-tosif-no-adding](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bal-tosif-no-adding)
    - [kilayim-forbidden-mixture](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kilayim-forbidden-mixture)
    - [lending-interest-ribbis](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lending-interest-ribbis)
    - [maakeh](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/maakeh)
    - [maaser-tithes](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/maaser-tithes)
    - [mezuzah](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mezuzah)

Mada

- [hashkafah-philosophy](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hashkafah-philosophy)
- [theology](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/theology)
- [astronomy](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/astronomy)
- [pikuachnefesh-danger-life](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pikuachnefesh-danger-life)
- [shemos-sacred-names](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shemos-sacred-names)
- [nevua-prophecy](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nevua-prophecy)
- [derech-eretz-manners](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/derech-eretz-manners)
- [middos-character-traits](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/middos-character-traits)
- [lashon-hara-slander](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lashon-hara-slander)
- [torah-study](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/torah-study)
- [rabbis](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rabbis)
- [idolatry](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/idolatry)
- [bowing-kneeling](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bowing-kneeling)
- [gentiles](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gentiles)
- [sorcery-magic-kishuf](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sorcery-magic-kishuf)
- [shaving](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shaving)
- [lo-yilbash](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lo-yilbash)
- [tattoo](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tattoo)
- [repentance-teshuvah](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/repentance-teshuvah)

Ahava

- [shema](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shema)
- [tefilla](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tefilla)
- [shemona-esrei](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shemona-esrei)
- [torah-service](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/torah-service)
- [torah-reading](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/torah-reading)
- [parsha-torah-portion](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/parsha-torah-portion)
- [haftarah](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/haftarah)
- [birchas-kohanim](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/birchas-kohanim)
- [tefilin](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tefilin)
- [mezuzah](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mezuzah)
- [sefer-torah](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sefer-torah)
- [safrus](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/safrus)
- [tzitzis](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tzitzis)
- [techeles](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/techeles)
- [tallit-gadol](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tallit-gadol)
- [tallit-katan](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tallit-katan)
- [blessing](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/blessing)
- [bentching](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bentching)
- [zimun](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/zimun)
- [netilat-yadayim-washing](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/netilat-yadayim-washing)
- [derech-eretz-manners](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/derech-eretz-manners)
- [shehecheyanu](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shehecheyanu)
- [kiddush-levanah](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kiddush-levanah)
- [brit-milah](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/brit-milah)
- [prayer-book](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/prayer-book)

Zmanim

- [eruv-chatzerot](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/eruv-chatzerot)
- [shofar](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shofar)
- [sukkah](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sukkah)
- [mishloach-manot](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mishloach-manot)

Kedusha

- [family-members](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/family-members)
- [adultery](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/adultery)
- [nidah](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nidah)
- [pregnancy-birth](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pregnancy-birth)
- [gerut-conversion](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gerut-conversion)
- [mamzer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mamzer)
- [kohen-priest](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kohen-priest)
- [negia](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/negia)
- [yichud-seclusion](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/yichud-seclusion)
- [kashrut-kosher](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kashrut-kosher)
- [animals](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/animals)
- [food](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/food)
- [honey](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/honey)
- [eggs](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/eggs)
- [dairy](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dairy)
- [chalav-yisrael-jewishmilk](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chalav-yisrael-jewishmilk)
- [fish](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fish)
- [meat](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/meat)
- [blood](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/blood)
- [gid-hanashe](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gid-hanashe)
- [basar-bechalav](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/basar-bechalav)
- [cooking-bishul](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cooking-bishul)
- [yashan-chadash](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/yashan-chadash)
- [orla-revai](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/orla-revai)
- [grapes-wine](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grapes-wine)
- [gentiles](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gentiles)
- [shiurim-measurements](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shiurim-measurements)
- [bitul-batel-null](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bitul-batel-null)
- [kashering-kosherization](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kashering-kosherization)
- [tevilas-keilim-dipping](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tevilas-keilim-dipping)
- [slaughter-shochet-shecht](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/slaughter-shochet-shecht)
- [shiluach-haken](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shiluach-haken)

Haflaah

- [sheker-false](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sheker-false)
- [nedarim-vows](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nedarim-vows)
- [nozir](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nozir)

Zeraim

- [agriculture](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/agriculture)
- [kilayim-forbidden-mixture](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kilayim-forbidden-mixture)
- [shatnez](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shatnez)
- [leket-shichecha-peah](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/leket-shichecha-peah)
- [tzedakah-charity](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tzedakah-charity)
- [maaser-tithes](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/maaser-tithes)
- [orla-revai](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/orla-revai)
- [bikkurim-first-fruits](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bikkurim-first-fruits)
- [separating-challah](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/separating-challah)
- [pidyon-haben](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pidyon-haben)
- [bechor-firstborn](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bechor-firstborn)
- [shmita](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shmita)
- [shofar](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shofar)
- [levites-leviyim](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/levites-leviyim)

Avoda

- [bigdei-kehunah](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bigdei-kehunah)
- [korban](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/korban)

Korbanot

- [bechor-firstborn](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bechor-firstborn)

Taharah

- [tumah-ritual-impurity](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tumah-ritual-impurity)
- [mikvah-ritual-bath](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mikvah-ritual-bath)
- [netilat-yadayim-washing](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/netilat-yadayim-washing)

Nezikin

- [gezel-stealing](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gezel-stealing)
- [murder](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/murder)

Kinyan

- [transactions](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/transactions)
- [slave-serve-eved-avadim](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/slave-serve-eved-avadim)

Mishpatim

- [borrowing](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/borrowing)
- [estates-inheritance](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/estates-inheritance)

Shoftim

- [sanhedrin-high-court](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sanhedrin-high-court)
- [beit-din-court](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/beit-din-court)
- [mourning-aveilus](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mourning-aveilus)
- [messiah](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/messiah)

Comment: @DoubleAA, this has changed it from being a list of mitzvos, to a list of categories of halachos. Not that that's bad, I like it! Thanks!

Comment: What had you intended by mitzvot?

Comment: The Rambam (leshitatei!) counts 'din nachalot' as a mitzva for instance :)

Comment: @DoubleAA Not "estates-inheritance" for example. There are mitzvos involved, certainly, but the broad category is not one.

Comment: Well, then Mishneh Torah might not have been such a good choice. The Rambam was quite thorough!

Comment: @DoubleAA, no, I think I like this idea better than mine

Comment: It seems pretty much all of the Holidays section can be imported to here.

Comment: @DoubleAA, maybe import by reference?  I suspect we'll be better off with multiple (per-broad-topic) answers like are starting to evolve, rather than one humongous one, but others should speak up.  (Also, not being fluent in Mishneh Torah, I wouldn't automatically know how to use its organization scheme -- happy to learn, but if it would involve splitting up the holidays so they're not in calendar order any more, that would make it harder for people like me.  Though with luck MT does a better job of staying on-topic than the g'mara. :-) )

Comment: Should we add in subsections for each Halchot, or just leave it split by Sefer?

Comment: @HodofHod ^^^^^

Comment: @DoubleAA you mean like making pidyon haben a sub-category of bechor, but still within Zeraim? Sure!

Comment: @HodofHod No I mean now I just have Mada, Ahava, Zemanim... listed. Should I also put in Yesodei Hatorah, Deot, Talmud Torah, Avoda Zara, Teshuva, Tefilah...?

Comment: @DoubleAA I think so, it will make it a little bit easier to read, I think.

Comment: @HodofHod The problem is it leads to a lot of repetition. For instance, agriculture will get listed many different times in Zeraim.

Answer (score 1):

Times and seasons:

---

- [calendar](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/calendar), [zemanim](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/zemanim), [months](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/months), [summer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/summer)
- [time](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/time), [time-zone](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/time-zone), [evening-night](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/evening-night)

---

[shabbat](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shabbat)

- [melacha-creative-work](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/melacha-creative-work), [muktzeh](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/muktzeh)
- [shabbat-songs](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shabbat-songs)
- [challah-shabbat-bread](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/challah-shabbat-bread)
- [aishes-chayil](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/aishes-chayil)
- [yom-shabbaton](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/yom-shabbaton) (guess)
- [havdalah](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/havdalah), [motzei-shabbos](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/motzei-shabbos)

---

[yom-tov](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/yom-tov), [chagim-holidays](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chagim-holidays) (see also: [hallel](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hallel), [shehecheyanu](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shehecheyanu))

- [passover](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/passover) (see also [yetziat-mitzrayim](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/yetziat-mitzrayim), [egypt](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/egypt))

  - [passover-seder-hagada](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/passover-seder-hagada), [four-cups-wine](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/four-cups-wine), [marror-bitter-herbs](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/marror-bitter-herbs)
  - [eliyahu-hanavi](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/eliyahu-hanavi)
  - [chametz-leaven](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chametz-leaven), [selling-mechirat-chametz](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/selling-mechirat-chametz)
  - [kitniyos-semigrain-legume](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kitniyos-semigrain-legume), [gebrochts](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gebrochts)
  - [matzah](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/matzah)
  - [plagues-makkos](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/plagues-makkos)
  - [nissan](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nissan)
- [yom-hashoah](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/yom-hashoah) (see also: [anti-semitism](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/anti-semitism), [holocaust-shoah](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/holocaust-shoah))
- [yom-hazikaron](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/yom-hazikaron), [yom-haatzmaut](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/yom-haatzmaut)
- [sefirat-ha-omer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sefirat-ha-omer), [lag-ba-omer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lag-ba-omer)
- [shavuos](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shavuos)  (see also: [har-sinai](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/har-sinai), [dairy](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dairy))

  - [bikkurim-first-fruits](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bikkurim-first-fruits)
- [three-weeks](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/three-weeks), [nine-days](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nine-days), [tisha-bav](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tisha-bav)  (see also: [churban-destruction](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/churban-destruction), [golus-exile](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/golus-exile))
- [elul](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/elul)
- [15th-of-av](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/15th-of-av)
- [rosh-hashanah-new-year](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rosh-hashanah-new-year)

  - [selichot](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/selichot)
  - [repentance-teshuvah](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/repentance-teshuvah)
  - [shofar](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shofar)
- [yom-kippur](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/yom-kippur) (see also [nedarim-vows](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nedarim-vows))
- [sukkot](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sukkot)

  - [sukkah](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sukkah)
  - [lulav-etrog-arba-minim](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lulav-etrog-arba-minim)
  - [hoshana-rabbah](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hoshana-rabbah)
  - [shmini-atzeres](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shmini-atzeres)
  - [simchat-torah](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/simchat-torah)
- [chanuka](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chanuka)  (see also: [oil](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/oil))

  - [menora-chanukia](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/menora-chanukia)
- [tu-bishvat](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tu-bishvat) (see also: [trees](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/trees))
- [purim](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/purim) (see also [megillat-esther](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/megillat-esther), [inebriation](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/inebriation))

  - [mishloach-manot](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mishloach-manot)
  - [hamantashen](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hamantashen)
  - [four-parshiot](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/four-parshiot), [parshat-zachor](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/parshat-zachor)
- [chol-hamoed](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chol-hamoed)
- [rosh-chodesh-new-month](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rosh-chodesh-new-month)  (see also: [kiddush-levanah](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kiddush-levanah))
- [fast-days](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fast-days)

---

[kiddush](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kiddush), [kiddush-cup](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kiddush-cup), [candle-lighting](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/candle-lighting)

See also: [non-jewish-holidays](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/non-jewish-holidays)

Comment: This completes my first pass through the whole tag list looking for time/season/yomtov-related tags.  Note that I'm not consuming the "see also"s; they're just there for reference.  Corrections always welcome, of course!

Comment: Maybe omit purim-torah-in-jest because we don't want people to use it?

Comment: @msh210, that's fine with me.

Comment: Is there any reason why [tag:four-parshiot] and [tag:parshat-zachor] are included in Pesach rather than Purim? Their laws are mentioned in the Shulchan Aruch before the laws of Purim, and they start before Purim and end after Purim and before Pesach.

Comment: @ba, good point, especially zachor (since it has its own tag).  I initially learned them as "four special parshiyot leading up to Pesach" so that's probably why I did this, but I agree with you and will fix.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is useful at all, or if the nuschaos tags should go elsewhere, but:

- [gentiles](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gentiles)

  - [christianity](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/christianity)
  - [islam](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/islam)
  - [idolatry](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/idolatry) (perhaps?)
- [am-yisrael-jewish-nation](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/am-yisrael-jewish-nation)

  - [ashkenazi](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ashkenazi)

    - [chasidut-hasidism](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chasidut-hasidism) (also: [chassidic-rebbe](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chassidic-rebbe))

      - [breslov](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/breslov)
      - [chabad](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chabad) (also: [nusach-ari](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nusach-ari))
  - [sephardi-mizrachi-eastern](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sephardi-mizrachi-eastern)
  - [yemenite-temani](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/yemenite-temani)
  - [kohen-priest](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kohen-priest)
  - [levites-leviyim](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/levites-leviyim)
  - [shevatim-12-tribes](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shevatim-12-tribes)
  - [yeshiva-school](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/yeshiva-school)

    - [mir](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mir)

Probably to split off into another answer:

- [tefilla](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tefilla)

  - [nuschaot](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nuschaot)

    - [nusach-ashkenaz](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nusach-ashkenaz)
    - [nusach-sefard](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nusach-sefard)
    - [nusach-ari](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nusach-ari)
    - [nusach-edot-hammizrach](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nusach-edot-hammizrach)
  - [shacharis-morning-prayer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shacharis-morning-prayer), [musaf](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/musaf), [mincha-afternoon-prayer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mincha-afternoon-prayer), [maariv](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/maariv)
  - [shemona-esrei](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shemona-esrei)
  - [tachanun](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tachanun)
  - [yizkor](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/yizkor)
  - ...

Comment: Perhaps under am-yisrael should also go (kohen, levi, yisroel), and (orthodox, conservative, reform).