# Are the [bava-kama], [baba-metziah], and [baba-batra] tags for the Gemara or the Mishna?

Tags: support, specific-tag, tags

None of these tags has a tag wiki excerpt that explains which one, and I'd... like to write one? :P

But seriously, are they for the Mishna or the Gemara?

Comment: Thanks for helping out with tag wikis!

Comment: there are also bavas for keilim. perhaps we should rename all these as bava-x-nezikin.

Comment: @DoubleAA Have you ever seen, in any other contemporary context, B"K, B"M, or B"B explicitly disambiguated like that where other tractate titles wouldn't be?

Comment: @IsaacMoses Other tractate titles? What other tractate titles would need to be clarified? "Nezikin" here isn't the Seder; it's the [Masekhet](https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%9E%D7%A1%D7%9B%D7%AA_%D7%A0%D7%96%D7%99%D7%A7%D7%99%D7%9F). Keilim, especially in the Tosefta, is still regularly split into BK BM BB, and in cases of ambiguity I've seen people clarify which Bava they refer to. It's often clear from context, and most people don't learn Keilim all that often anyway. Consider on our site http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/53955/759

Comment: @DoubleAA, I'm talking about convention. Literally every Judaism expert who sees the tag name "bava-kama" will assume, correctly, that it applies to that volume, whatever its technical status, in Nezikin. For Keilim, I'd support whatever level of aggregation volume seems to support.

Comment: @IsaacMoses I'm not saying this is a major issue, but it doesn't complicate things at all. I'm not suggesting we just use "Masekhet-Nezikin" for all 30 chapters and hope everyone figures it out. What I'm suggesting is both technically correct and less ambiguous. What's the problem?

Comment: @DoubleAA The clarification you propose is like a ventriloquist's dummy when the ventriloquist is halfway across the room. That is, it *sounds* good but it's not gonna *do* much; but, hey, there's no real 'arm in it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All of the specific-*masechet* tags are for *mishna*, *g'mara*, and/or *tosefta* in that *masechet*, either Bavli or Yerushalmi.  I spot-checked a few from [this list](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/998/472) and didn't find a tag wiki at all, let alone one stating a restriction.  Based on the traffic we've seen on these tags, I don't think we need to subdivide them.

Comment: If someone wants to make very clear that their question only applies to one rendering of the tractate, they can also add [tag:mishna], [tag:talmud-gemara], [tag:talmud-bavli], [tag:talmud-yerushalmi], or [tag:tosefta].

Comment: @IsaacMoses And if we ever get enough questions about BK Tosefta, we can separate it's own tag then.