# Seeking list of MY tags

Tags: discussion, tags

There seem to be some 500 allowed tags on MY.  Where do I find a list of them. (When I click on tags, I get a screen with a dozen and an option to click through 50+ such screens.)

Comment: What's wrong with just clicking through?

Comment: Note anyone with 300 rep can make new tags http://judaism.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/create-tags

Comment: @DoubleAA clicking through 50+ screens is not a user friendly option.  If the moderators want the tags to be used, and used properly, there should be an easier way to access a list of the tags.

Comment: It seems like a user friendly option to me. Why do you need to see the whole list in order to use them?

Answer (score 4):

The tags list, which shows 36 at a time, is the official way to browse tags.  If you type some text into the box (at least three characters), it acts as a search/filter.  There might be a way to get the full list through the SE API, which I don't know much about.

This interface is definitely Not Ideal.  Some time ago, people here started an effort to organize our tags logically rather than by frequency or alphabetically: [Systematic list of tags](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/996/systematic-list-of-tags).  Browsing the answers there might help you find what you're looking for, though the project is incomplete.  (Feel free to add to it!  It's Community Wiki for a reason.)

That question contains a list (now out of date) of all tags on the site.  That list was generated somehow.  Perhaps that code still exists somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

That [tags](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/tags) screen is the official way to do it, i'm afraid. To be precise, it actually shows 3 dozen on a page.

You can also use the search box on that page to try and find a specific tag, but be prepared to try several spellings.