# type of question to ask on MY

Tags: discussion, scope

I appreciate the forum to be able to ask questions. However, I want mine to be in sync with what the guidelines for the site are. Are questions on the weekly Parsha encouraged to be asked on the MY site?

Comment: Just be careful to make your question rock solid because you will get ripped apart otherwise. People here assume you have to know everything that they know before you ask the question.

Comment: We welcome questions from people at all levels of knowledge.  Do what work you can (make some effort like you would on any other SE site) and tell us where you are.  I've asked questions about concepts and *halachot* that were new to me and I don't know enough to be able to navigate some of our key sources on my own, yet people have been willing to help me.

Comment: @moses that's definitely not true. if you don't know everything before asking and there's some way to improve the question that you didn't realize, people will often point it out to you so you can do so. While it's best to have all the relevant info there from the outset, there's no shame in hitting the edit button

Comment: @Moses613 I admit that many of my parsha questions come from my previous knowledge of some aspect of the parsha, but, certainly not enough for the question that I'm asking. Unless I plan on answering my own question, when I post my question, I DON'T know all the answers! I think that's true with pretty much any question, here, not just parsha questions. I'm curious why you think that parsha questions in particular draws more of the factors you mentioned?

Answer (score 5):

Absolutely!  In fact, we have a [tag for each parsha](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/997/472).  Remember that questions stick around forever, so instead of asking about "this week's parsha" be sure to say what text you're asking about.  You can browse the existing questions, for example on [this week's portion of B'midbar](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bamidbar-parsha), to get a feel for what (and how) others have asked.

You might have noticed that the transliteration in the names of the tags is a little inconsistent.  That's the nature of crowd-sourced Jewish writing.  With luck you'll find the tag you're looking for without too much trouble, but if you ever start typing a parsha name and can't seem to find the tag, please let us know what you tried so we can consider adding a synonym.  You can ask a new meta question about it or bring it up in chat.

Comment: Ok great thank you

Comment: I know that we can suggest new tags. Briefly, how do you make one tag synonymous with another so that both appear as you type? Or is that only a moderator feature?

Comment: @DanF you can propose a synonym by going to the tag page and clicking on ["synonyms"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rGOtm.png).  The community then has to vote on these and it's not very visible, so you might want to bring it up in chat or ask on meta.  (Ignore the "merge" link in my screen shot; that's mod-only, but not a secret so I didn't bother to redo the screen shot after noticing.)